# Is my Gaussian Process implementation working correctly?

Tags: r, machine-learning, gaussian-process

I'm using the standard kernel: $K(x_1, x_2) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (\frac{(x_1-x_2)}{l})^2)$, with $l=1.0$.

I picked some arbitrary function, and then picked 15 points from which to learn from. Here's the graph I get when I plot those points, the real underlying function, and the learned conditional distributions confidence intervals.

[image]

I'm surprised that the confidence intervals are so "wobbly" and don't hug the real function more closely. Is this the normal behaviour? Am I getting these results because I'm not actually learning the value $l$ in the kernel and just plugging in $l=1.0$? Or is there possibly some bug in my code?

Comment: Sounds good. The function I was trying to learn is $3 \sin(.07x)$.

Comment: I've revised my answer. TLDR it looks like you were doing the right thing.

Comment: The reason for the 'wobbly'-ness is because your points are far apart relative to $\ell$. If you change $\ell$ to be 10, then you should see the estimate hug the true function more.

Answer (score 4):

I cooked this up really quick, so beware. But the results appear to be consistent with yours. If you think about it, the non-convex shapes make sense because they're relative to the **predicted** mean, and because the mean is estimated very near zero and `sigma` is small, this model will tend towards zero in between the data. Your plot omits the predicted means, which is why the behavior appears to be counter-intuitive. Gaussian process models have the property that they will interpolate exactly in the absence of signal noise, so that's why the predictions have the U shape.

[image: sigma is 1.0]

Playing with the `sigma` value will alter this effect, because it changes the behavior of the mean function between the observed data. Larger values of sigma produce dramatically different results. Below is a plot for sigma = 3.0.

The Gaussian process's interpolation property is why the confidence bands shrink to 0 where the data are observed. This is true for these models and all GP models which do not have observation noise, and omit a noise parameter. (To add a noise term, set `eta` to a positive value.)

[image: sigma is 3.0]

```
gaussian_kernel <- function(x, y, sigma){
    d_sq <- sum( (x - y) ^ 2)
    out <- exp(- 0.5 * d_sq / (sigma ^ 2))
    return(out)
}

get_K <- function(X, Y = "None", sigma=1.0){
    check <- all(Y == "None")
    if (check){
        size <- nrow(X)
        K <- matrix(1.0, nrow=size, ncol=size)
        for(i in 1:(size - 1) ){
            for(j in ((i + 1):size)){
                new_k <- gaussian_kernel(X[i,], X[j,], sigma=sigma)
                K[i,j] <- new_k
                K[j,i] <- new_k
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        size1 <- nrow(X)
        size2 <- nrow(Y)
        K <- matrix(0.0, size1, size2)
        for(i in 1:size1){
            for(j in 1:size2){
                K[i,j] <- gaussian_kernel(X[i,], Y[j,], sigma=sigma)
            }
        }
    }
    return(K)
}

eta <- 0.0

x <- matrix(seq(-60,60,length.out=15), ncol=1)
y <- 3 * sin(0.7 * x)
mu <- mean(y)

x_tilde <- matrix(seq(-60,60,length.out=1024)), ncol=1)

K <- get_K(x, sigma=1)
K_star <- get_K(x_tilde, x, sigma=1)
K_star_star <- get_K(x_tilde, sigma=1)

eye <- diag(nrow(x))

K_qr <- qr(K + eta * eye)
K_R <- qr.R(K_qr)
K_Q <- qr.Q(K_qr)


y_hat <- mu + K_star %*% backsolve(K_R, crossprod(K_Q, y - mu))
cov <- K_star_star - K_star %*% backsolve(K_R, t(K_Q) %*% t(K_star))

y_ci <- 2 * sqrt(diag(cov))

y_ci_upper <- y_hat + y_ci
y_ci_lower <- y_hat - y_ci

png("cv_gp.png", height=6, width=6, units="in", res=300)
    plot(x, y, xlim=c(-60,60), ylim=c(-4,4))
    x_poly <- c(rev(x_tilde), x_tilde)
    y_poly <- c(rev(y_ci_lower), y_ci_upper)
    polygon(x_poly, y_poly, col="grey")
    lines(x_tilde, y_hat, col="red", lwd=2)
    points(x,y,lwd=2)
dev.off()
```

To make these diagrams even more interesting, try randomly sampling the observed data.